# timeout continues to run after page click to other path in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am using yo:angular-fullstack generator to build my website. When a user registers to the site, it will send an activation email with a link. When a user clicks the link, it will show activation successful and a timeout to go to the home page. However, when the timeout has not finished and the user clicks any other link in the page, it jumps to other page with continuing running the timeout. Severally seconds later, the user will be still moved to the home page. The following code is about my timeout in angular js.

Comment: I think you missed the code.

Comment: Which following code? Read http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2548-don-t-forget-to-cancel-timeout-timers-in-your-destroy-events-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: Don't post the same question twice under a different user name. The first identical question has already been answered. Read the answers.

Answer (score 0):

**General use**

```
  var timer = $timeout(function(){
    // Do This and That
    $timeout.cancel(timer);
  }, 1000);
```

**$destroy event**

```
var promise = $timeout(doFunction, 1000);

$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
    $timeout.cancel(promise);
});
```

**$locationChangeStart**

```
var promise = $timeout(doFunction, 1000);

$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(){
    $timeout.cancel(promise);
});
```

Try with above one of approach.